# Oracle SQL: Extracting rows data into multiple columns using SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have one scenario where data are in table as follows:

```
Ser_num  File_name
1        DBA OBJECT~ALL_OBJECT
2        ./outfile_26094843.txt
3        ./outfile_26094844.txt
4        ./DataFile.txt
5        DBA OBJECT~AP_INVOICES_ALL
6        ./XXFA_GL_ICOMP_JOURNAL.rdf
7        ./outfile_26094844.txt
```

I have to extract data as follow

```
ALL_OBJECT
outfile_26094843.txt
outfile_26094844.txt
DataFile.txt
AP_INVOICES_ALL
XXFA_GL_ICOMP_JOURNAL.rdf
outfile_26094844.txt
```

please advise me SQL for this.

Comment: Try that one `select REPLACE(REPLACE(File_name, 'DBA OBJECT~', ''), './', '') from table;`  :-)

Comment: So, the input is in seven rows in the input, and in two columns. And the output is in one column **and a single row**, with the value being a string with newlines? (The value, in a single row, is text that extends over seven lines?) Then: in the input, are all the lines either like `DBA OBJECT~<more text here>` or `./<more text here>`, and you want to extract the "more text"? Finally: can the result be more than 4000 bytes long? (So VARCHAR2 will not suffice - the result must be a CLOB?)

Comment: @g00dy, I never thought that it could be this much easier. I was guessing for REGEXP. Thanks for letting me know some trick.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - well this case is simple - thus the solution. For a more elaborated pattern matching `REGEXP` is the answer of course. I'm not really sure that this exhaust the cases here, that's why I added a comment, as there might be some other cases ..

Comment: I agree. But the real programming is to play with the loopholes of the conditions and here is one of the greatest example.